# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'son['businesses']')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, yelp-fusion-api

Im getting this error "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'son['businesses']')"
Im not sure what is the issue is because when I was writing 'son['businesses'][1]['name']', I started with just 'son' and when i added '['businesses'][1]['name']' no error was thrown. but as I restarted my simulator it now throws an error.

```
const [son, setSon] = useState(null);
```

```
fetch("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=burger&location=90706&limit=2", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => db.collection("group")
            .doc(roomCode)
            .set(result))
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

```
const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            await db
                .collection('group')
                .doc(route.params.roomCode)
                .get()
                .then((documentSnapshot) => {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                        setSon(documentSnapshot.data());
                    } else {
                        console.log('hello');
                    }
                })

        } catch (err) {
            Alert.alert('There is something wrong!', err.message);
        }
    }
```

```
 useEffect(() => {
        console.log('completed');
        fetchData();
        
        console.log('son', son['businesses'][1]['name']);
        
    }, []);
```

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
//import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
//import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert, View, Image, FlatList, SafeAreaView} from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles";
import { doc, setDoc, getDoc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { db, auth } from "../../firestore";
import firebase from "firebase";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import IconMaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import Swiper from "react-native-deck-swiper";
import {BEARER_TOKEN} from '../hooks/yelp-api/config';

const DUMMY_DATA = [
    {
        restaurantName: 'Marufuku Ramen',
        occupation: "bricks",
        photoURL: "https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/ouK2VmW0SrI70jsJpTxJhw/1000s.jpg",
        age: 27,
        id: 123,

    },
    {
        restaurantName: 'Farmhouse Kitchen Thai Cuisine',
        occupation: "nothing",
        photoURL: "https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/kUlEaPpv0JGlHG_nrPr7wQ/1000s.jpg",
        age: 23,
        id: 124,
    },
    {
        restaurantName: 'Sotto Mare Oysteria & Seafood',
        occupation: "everything",
        photoURL: "https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/o3hIcGLMxV_5ynxEjGWGrw/1000s.jpg",
        age: 99,
        id: 125,
    }
]


const GroupSwipe = ({navigation, route, roomZipCode}) => {
    const roomCode = route.params.roomCode;
    const swipeRef = useRef(null);
    const [son, setSon] = useState({});
    //const [result, setresult] = useState()
    console.log('roomZipCode',roomZipCode);
    useEffect(() =>{
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", BEARER_TOKEN);
    
        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: myHeaders,
            redirect: 'follow'
        };
    
        fetch("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=burger&location=90706&limit=2", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => db.collection("group")
            .doc(roomCode)
            .set(result))
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
            

    })

        
    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            await db
                .collection('group')
                .doc(route.params.roomCode)
                .get()
                .then((documentSnapshot) => {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                        setSon(documentSnapshot.data());
                    } else {
                        console.log('hello');
                    }
                })

        } catch (err) {
            Alert.alert('There is something wrong!', err.message);
        }
    }
    
        
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("completed");
        fetchData().then((data) => {
            setSon(data);
            console.log("son", son["businesses"][1]["name"]);
        })
    }, []);
    // useEffect(() => {
    //     console.log('completed');
    //     fetchData();
        
    //     console.log('son', son['businesses'][1]['name']);
        
    // }, []);
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.safe}>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainerHome}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('GroupStart') }
                    style={styles.buttonHome}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonTextHome}>FOOD FIGHT</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.roomId}>    
                <Text style ={styles.roomIdText}>Room ID: {roomCode}</Text>
            </View>
            {/* <View style={styles.resturantName}>
                <Text style ={styles.resturantNameText}>Chick Fil A</Text>
            </View>  */}
            <View style={styles.cards}>
                <Swiper 
                ref={swipeRef}
                    containerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                    cards={DUMMY_DATA}
                    stackSize={3}
                    cardIndex={0}
                    animateCardOpacity
                    verticalSwipe={false}
                    renderCard={(card) => (
                        <View style={styles.cardstyle}
                        key={card.id} >
                            {/* style={tw("relative bg-white h-3/4 rounded-xl")}> */}
                            <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center', margin:10, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold',}}>{card.restaurantName}</Text>
                            <Image 
                                style={{ alignSelf: 'center', width: 300,
                                height: 300,resizeMode: 'contain', borderRadius: 5, 
                                margin:15, borderRadius: 20, justifyContent: 'center'}}
                                source={{ uri: card.photoURL }}
                                />
                        </View>
                        
                    )}
                />
            </View>
            <View style = {styles.functionList}>           
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}} style = {styles.functionButton}>                   
                        <Icon name="undo" size={50} color="#ECD55D" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => swipeRef.current.swipeLeft()} style = {styles.functionButton}>
                        <Icon name="times-circle-o" size={80} color="#AA4747" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => swipeRef.current.swipeRight()} style = {styles.functionButton}>
                        <Icon name="check-circle-o" size={80} color="#9DC151" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}} style = {styles.functionButton}>
                        <IconMaterialCommunityIcons name="star-circle-outline" size={55} color="#75B9DF" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
        
    )
}

export default GroupSwipe
```

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'son["businesses"][1]')]
> at node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.browser.esm.js:3561:30 in UploadTaskCompat.prototype.on

I have tried to use async function and await for the fetchData() but it didnt solve the issue.

Comment: Small note: you're missing a closing `)` on `.then(result => db.collection("group")`.

Comment: its there after the ```.set(results))```

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` runs when the component mount, update (if there are dependencies), and unmount (if there is a return method).

What's happening here is when the component mount, it fires off `useEffect` and the following things happen:

- `console.log('completed')` runs right away
- then the second line executes `fetchData()` which is an async call and because you're not awaiting it here, the third line executes `console.log('son', son['businesses'][1]['name']);` and at that point, the `fetchData` is still trying to fetch the data from the API and therefore the third line fails as the `son` is still null.

The easiest solution to this is to do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("completed");
  fetchData().then((data) => {
      setSon(data);
      console.log("son", son["businesses"][1]["name"]);
  })
}, []);
```

Comment: i tried this and i get this error "[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'son["businesses"]')]"

Comment: can you share more information and maybe if possible, put minimal code to codesandbox.io or any other online IDE for better context.

Comment: im not familiar with codesandbox.io. so i added more to current post

Comment: can you also copy/paste the whole error trace you're seeing in the terminal?

Comment: another thing is that are you trying to fetch data from yelp, save it to db, and then trying to fetch the same data from db?

Comment: I added the full error trace to the main post at the bottom.

Comment: Yeah im fetching from yelp, then saving to the db, and going to fetch it from the db. The first two steps will be done in a different part of my app compared to final step of fetching the information from the db. It so that a group of users can access the same information.